# Unable to fetch data from service in component in Angular 2

Tags: service, angular, promise, components, provider

I am using Angular 2.0.0-beta.15. I am trying to get data from service in a component. Following is the piece of code in component.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {UserService} from '../services/user.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  templateUrl: './views/parentUser.html',
  providers: [UserService]
})
export class ParentUserComponent {  
  constructor(private _userService:UserService) {
    this._userService.getCurrentUser().subscribe(data => console.log(data));
  }
}
```

Now my UserService piece of code is

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private currentUser = {
        username: '',
        role: '',
        targetURL: ''
  };

  setCurrentUser(currentUser) {
    this.currentUser.username = currentUser.username;
    this.currentUser.role = currentUser.role;
    this.currentUser.targetURL = currentUser.targetURL;
    console.log('current User:' + JSON.stringify(this.currentUser));
  }

  getCurrentUser() {
    return Observable.of(this.currentUser);
  }
}
```

My boots.ts is as follows:

```
///<reference path="../../node_modules/angular2/typings/browser.d.ts"/>
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, RouteConfig, Location,      LocationStrategy, HashLocationStrategy} from 'angular2/router';
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';
import {UserService} from './services/user.service';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, HTTP_PROVIDERS,    provide(LocationStrategy, {useClass: HashLocationStrategy}), UserService]);
```

Now when i try to run my component. it throws error like 
Error: Uncaught (in promise): No provider for a!
angular2-polyfills.js:528 Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for a! 
NoProviderError {message:"No provider for a!, stack: "Error: DI Exception↵    at NoProviderError.BaseExc…odules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js:11788:19)", keys: Array[3], injectors: Array[3]}

Can somebody guide me?

Comment: Could you use the .dev.js files for Angular2 (for example angular.dev.js)? This way we will messages easier to understand ;-)

Comment: @ThierryTemplier - yes I am using .dev.js for angular 2.

Comment: Okay. If you remove the constructor of your component, do you have the same error?

Comment: @ThierryTemplier - I tried to remove constructor and used ngOnInit to call that method. Now error is like 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentUser' of undefined in [null] '. Sorry I am new to Angular 2, just wanted to know like why you mentioned to remove constructor?

Comment: I wanted to be sure that the dependency injection at this level was the problem...

Comment: ok @ThierryTemplier. But i am confused and not clear why dependency injection in constructor was causing error. My intention was simple, once i logged in, i am setting user details in service, so that i can fetch in other components. But I am unable to ..

Comment: Can you create a plunker out of it so we can see the error?

Comment: @PierreUrban - thanks a lot for asking. But I have solved it myself. The solution to above problem was what Thierry Templier said. But when i solved that error,it caused other issues, which was related to my code. I revisited my entire code and made so many changes and after that above mentioned error was not there.